# Wanting to plot a bar chart from data in a text file in Python

Tags: python, file, plot, text, charts

Ok, I'm sufficiently confused and not making any progress at all. New to python, and using Pycharm/python 3

I have a text file saved on my desktop (Win 10). The file contains a name, a comma and a number.

e.g.

name1, number

name2, number

name3, number

name4, number

(etc)

The names are all different, and the numbers are not ordered, and some are the same and some are not.

The numbers are integers, and all I'm trying to do is make a bar chart plot. The names along the x-axis and the numbers (in descending order) for the y-axis.

I have tried and tried and tried and tried and I cannot get this to work.

I can manage to access the file, but can't do anything with it. I can get the output I want, but I can't access it. I can get bits and pieces but I can't put it together. I know this is probably an easy thing, but nothing makes sense, and nothing seems to work anymore, and could use a hand.

How do you do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be the simplest implementation:

```py
#import libraries 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
#read your txt file which is formatted as a csv into a dataframe and name your cols
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.txt',names=['name','number'])
print(df.head())

#plot it
plt.bar(df.name,df.number) #this is equivalent to df['name'],df['number']
plt.show()
```

There are a lot of other ways to make this more complicated, improve your plot ensure your datatypes are correct etc. but this will hopefully get you going.

Comment: Thanks brobertsp, but this throws a number of errors that I probably have no hope of fixing.

Comment: You changed the 'my_file.txt' to whatever the filepath you have is? As long as you did that and your file is formatted as name, number each on its own line this should work. You can always post your errors on here as well for further explanation of your problem.

Comment: brobertsp --- yes, I did make that change, and I know it works because I accessed the file and did a print and it DOES show, so I believe I am accessing it correctly. Thanks for all your help....errors...that's just it, there are NO errors.....it says: "Process finished with exit code 0"...and it throws up a plot window with axes, numbers, tick marks....and no plot. Now....I did find a code snippet for bar charts and histograms and I can copy that in and run it, and that gives a nice chart....works great, but for some reason it doesn't like my text file I guess.....it's pretty frustrating, lol

Comment: brobertsp ---- I can run the following and it accesses and prints the contents of a text file on my desktop. file1 = open(r"C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_file_name.txt", "r")

print("Output of Read function is ")
print(file1.read())

Comment: brobertsp --- Ok...I'm so confused, BUT....I changed the path to a different text file, ran the program (same result), changed it back to the main text file....and now it's working. It prints a nice chart....names along the bottom, sorted.....it's beautiful, I'm grateful to you, but I don't understand why all this happened this way. I'm 99% sure it was something I was doing, but I don't know what....thank you, the only thing I need to do it print the names along the x-axis so they are at an angle so they all fit and can be read. I appreciate your help.

Comment: brobertsp --- Thanks again, but one more question....the names along the x-axis are all jumbled up. hHey are somewhat along the x-axis, but many are on top of each other. How would I get these to correspond to the numbers in the text file and print out one for each tick?

Comment: @fiz it would be helpful if you would update your question with an example of the script you are using and an example of your output. Additionally, if your text file(s) look different than the example you should update those as well. You should endeavor to follow the Stack Overflow MWE guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: brobertsp ---- Here's my code: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
filename = r"C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\my_text_file.txt"
with open(filename) as file:
    entries = [x.split(",") for x in file.readlines()]  # Read the text, splitting on comma.
    entries = [(x[0], int(x[1])) for x in entries]  # Turn the numbers into ints.
    entries.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)  # Sort by y-values.
x_coords = [x[0] for x in entries]
y_coords = [x[1] for x in entries]
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.bar(x_coords, y_coords)  # Draw a bar chart
plt.show()

Comment: brobertsp ---- I made changes in the names so it's first name and last name, and rotated 90 degrees, which works, everything fits, but I don't like the way that looks. I'd rather have the 45 degree rotation, but I will accept that if necessary. Also, the chart window is cutting off the bottom of the names, so that's another problem that needs fixed. I don't know how to make open space around the chart so the whole thing can be easily read. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I have been working on this all day. Made *some* progress. I have solved a couple things I was asking about, and now I'd like to be able to change the color of the chart title, x and y-axis labels. I would also like to add a bit of space between the axis labels and their respective axis. I will post after this so you can see the code. Thank you (again)

Comment: Well, I guess I can't post my code because it's too long, so I'll try and post part here and the rest in another comment.      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = r"C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Working Student File Final Output_2.txt"

with open(filename) as file:
    entries = [x.split(",") for x in file.readlines()]  # Read the text, splitting on comma.
    entries = [(x[0], int(x[1])) for x in entries]  # Turn the numbers into ints.
    entries.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)  # Sort by y-values.

Comment: x_coords = [x[0] for x in entries]
y_coords = [x[1] for x in entries]
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.bar(x_coords, y_coords)  # Draw a bar chart
plt.tight_layout()  # Make room for the names at the bottom
# Next two lines adjust the space around the top, bottom, left & right around the plot
plt.plot()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.4)
plt.xlabel('Student Names', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Frequency of Student Visits', fontsize=12)
ax.tick_params(colors='r')
plt.title('Stark State Tutoring Summer 2020', fontsize=15)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
plt.show()

Comment: Hey fiz sorry I would suggest that you open a new question at some point because your original question was about reading in a text file and plotting it. It seems like that has been accomplished? If you have additional questions about matplotlib formatting that should go in another question and you should look at some other answers for that as there are many, many on SO. Additionally, in the future it is MUCH easier to read if you edit your original question and add code to a code block as @JimmyCarlos and I have done. That is much preferable to posting code in the comments.

Comment: brobertsp ----- ok....you're probably right, but thanks for the help with everything!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filepath = r"C:\Users*me*\Desktop\my_file.txt"
with open(filepath) as file:
    entries = [x.split(",") for x in file.readlines()] # Read the text, splitting on comma.
    entries = [(x[0],int(x[1])) for x in entries] # Turn the numbers into ints.
    entries.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True) # Sort by y-values.
    x_coords = [x[0] for x in entries]
    y_coords = [x[1] for x in entries]
    plt.bar(x_coords,y_coords) # Draw a bar chart
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you....there's no errors, but the plot is empty. It's probably on my end, and not accessing the text file correctly. How do I access the file on my desktop. I use: C:\Users\*me*\Desktop\my_file.txt

Comment: Sure, I've fixed it to how you would load a filepath.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, yes, I did do the file path right, and the code runs with no errors, but the plot window is blank.

Comment: Should "filename" be changed to "filepath"? Even if so, I tried making the change and still get a blank chart. It plots the axes and the tick marks are there, but everything else is blank.